# How to determine the specific heat of methanol from calorimeter data?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

> A $\pu{25.95 g}$ sample of methanol at $\pu{35.6 ^\circ C}$ is added to a $\pu{38.65 g}$ sample of ethanol at $\pu{24.7 ^\circ C}$ in a constant pressure calorimeter. If the final temperature of the combined liquids is $\pu{28.5 ^\circ C}$ and heat capacity of the calorimeter is $\pu{19.3 J/^\circ C}$ determine the specific heat of methanol. The heat capacity of ethanol is $\pu{2.46 J/(g * ^\circ C)}$.

\begin{align}
  q_\mathrm{methanol} &= -q_\mathrm{ethanol}\\
  msT &= -msT\\
  \pu{25.95 g} \cdot  (\pu{28.5 ^\circ C} - \pu{35.6 ^\circ C}) \cdot  s
    &= -\pu{38.65 g} \cdot  (\pu{28.5 ^\circ C} - \pu{24.7 ^\circ C})
       \cdot  \pu{2.46 J/(g* ^\circ C)}\\
\therefore s &= \pu{1.96 J/(g * ^\circ C)}
\end{align}

The correct answer, however, is $\pu{2.36 J/(g * ^\circ C)}$.
I think that there is a mistake in my solution, because the heat capacity of the calorimeter is given, and I didn't use it.

Could anyone explain where I have been wrong?

Comment: It's a good idea to include units in your equation. Where does the number 38.5 come from? (I think you mean 28.5). Also, why are you multiplying the right side by 2.64?

Comment: yes i meant that.. 2.46 is the specific heat of ethanol I got it from the book

Comment: You don't mention *ethanol* in your problem, you only mention *methanol*. Could you double check the question you've written. Is it that you are given a sample of methanol and it is added to a sample of *ethanol*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have included the heat capacitance of the calorimeter. Think about it, if the calorimeter was at $\pu{24.7 ^\circ C}$ before the methanol was added and then it rose $\pu{3.8 ^\circ C}$ along with the liquids, where did the energy come from to increase its temperature? Since you know that the heat capacitance of the calorimeter is $\pu{19.3 J/^\circ C}$ then you can find out how much energy the calorimeter absorbed to increase in temperature by multiplying its heat capacitance by its temperature increase. I.e. $\pu{19.3J/^\circ C} \cdot \pu{3.8 ^\circ C} = $ *"Joules absorbed by the calorimeter"*.

Then we simply apply the heat lost equals heat gained concept:

$$\begin{multline}
\pu{25.95 g} \cdot (\pu{35.6 ^\circ C} - \pu{28.5 ^\circ C}) \cdot S \\
  = \pu{38.65 g} \cdot (\pu{28.5 ^\circ C} - \pu{24.7 ^\circ C}) 
    \cdot \pu{2.46 J/(g* ^\circ C)} + \pu{19.3J/^\circ C} 
    \cdot \pu{3.8 ^\circ C}
\end{multline}$$

After rearranging, we get $S = \pu{2.36 J/(g * ^\circ C)}$.